# Vimeo is not counting views coming from the app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, view, vimeo, vimeo-api

Vimeo is not counting views coming from the app, since the 12 January 2020.

The problem goes for all videoes.

The app is called Tidslommen and can be downloaded in Google Play and on the Apple App Store

I have embedded Vimeo in a mobile application using the Vimeo unity SDK (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk).

All videos are private and hidden from vimeo.com (http://vimeo.com/).

The videos are playing as intended in the app, but the views are not counting.

Here is the request log produced by a view in the app:

```
Playing video: POI-Istidsruten-Sagnlandet-000-Intro - "/videos/343618571"
{"uri":"/videos/343618571","name":"POI-Istidsruten-Sagnlandet-000-Intro","description":null,"type":"video","link":"https://vimeo.com/343618571","duration":47,"width":1280,"language":null,"height":720,"embed":{"buttons":{"like":true,"watchlater":true,"share":true,"embed":true,"hd":false,"fullscreen":true,"scaling":true},"logos":{"vimeo":true,"custom":{"active":false,"link":null,"sticky":false}},"title":{&..." (https://vimeo.com/343618571%22,%22duration%22:47,%22width%22:1280,%22language%22:null,%22height%22:720,%22embed%22:%7B%22buttons%22:%7B%22like%22:true,%22watchlater%22:true,%22share%22:true,%22embed%22:true,%22hd%22:false,%22fullscreen%22:true,%22scaling%22:true%7D,%22logos%22:%7B%22vimeo%22:true,%22custom%22:%7B%22active%22:false,%22link%22:null,%22sticky%22:false%7D%7D,%22title%22:%7B%22name%22:%22user%22,%22owner%22:%22user%22,%22portrait%22:%22user%22%7D,%22playbar%22:true,%22volume%22:tr...) <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/343618571?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=114339\ (https://player.vimeo.com/video/343618571?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=114339%5C) " width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen title="POI-Istidsruten-Sagnlandet-000-Intro"></iframe>","badges":{"hdr":false,"live":{"streaming":false,"archived":false},"staff_pick":{"normal":false,"best_of_the_month":false,"best_of_the_year":false,"premiere":false},"vod":false,"weekend_challenge":false}},"created_time":"2019-06-21T09:17:12+00:00","modified_time":"2020-01-04T20:49:44+00:00","release_time":"2019-06-21T09:17:12+00:00","content_rating":["unrated"],"license":null,"privacy":{"view":"disable","embed":"public","download":true,"add":true,"comments":"anybody"},"pictures":{"uri":"/videos/343618571/pictures/792833266","active":true,"type":"custom","sizes":[{"width":100,"height":75,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/792833266_100x75.jpg?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F792833266_100x75.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"},{"width":200,"height":150,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/792833266_200x150.jpg?r=pad","link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=h... (https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/792833266_100x75.jpg?r=pad%22,%22link_with_play_button%22:%22https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F792833266_100x75.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png%22%7D,%7B%22width%22:200,%22height%22:150,%22link%22:%22https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/792833266_200x150.jpg?r=pad%22,%22link_with_play_button%22:%22https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F792833...) rating","spam","causes harm"]}}},"user":{"uri":"/users/83054483","name":"Museum Vestsjælland","link":"https://vimeo.com/user83054483","location":"","bio":null,"short_bio":null,"created_time":"2018-03-20T07:40:57+00:00","pictures":{"uri":"/users/83054483/pictures/28295357","active":true,"type":"custom","sizes":[{"width":30,"height":30,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/28295357_30x30"},{"width":75,"hei... (https://vimeo.com/user83054483%22,%22location%22:%22%22,%22bio%22:null,%22short_bio%22:null,%22created_time%22:%222018-03-20T07:40:57+00:00%22,%22pictures%22:%7B%22uri%22:%22/users/83054483/pictures/28295357%22,%22active%22:true,%22type%22:%22custom%22,%22sizes%22:%5B%7B%22width%22:30,%22height%22:30,%22link%22:%22https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/28295357_30x30%22%7D,%7B%22width%22:75,%22height%22:75,%22link%22:%22https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/28295357_75x75%22%7D,%7B%22width%22:100,%22heigh...)
```

Unity version
2018.4.13f1

Operating system
iOS, Android and Editor

Comment: It's possible that the app is either not using the normal viewing display, or it's sending a different non-standard User Agent to request the resource, which could lead to Vimeo blocking that User Agent from the view count. (Sometimes the UA can be changed, but sometimes that's also possibly deceptive.)